# Python - Calcular a matriz transposta

Tags: python, matriz, map

Preciso calcular a matriz transposta usando a função map do python. Mas, estou não estou conseguindo resolver.

```
def transp(a):
    for i in range(2):
        for j in a:
            return [a[i][j]]
        
list (map(transp,matrix))
```

Surge a seguinte mensagem de erro - TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

o que eu faço para corrigir esse bug?

Comment: Coloca para gente a declaração e povoamento de `matrix` para nós testarmos.

Comment: Se uma das respostas abaixo resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, escolha a que você mais gostou e marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique à vontade para comentar.

Answer (score 5):

Uma solução usando list comprehension:

```py
A=[[1,2],[4,6]]

#printa as linhas da matriz A
for i in A:
    print(i)

A_t=[[k[0] for k in A],[k[1] for k in A]]

#printa as linhas da transposta de A
for i in A_t:
    print(i)
```

Essa solução usa o fato de que uma matriz pode ser vista como uma lista de listas e que a transposição consiste simplesmente na transformação de linhas em colunas.

Operações com matrizes podem se tornar muito complexas dependendo da aplicação. Por essa razão recomendo estudar implementações dessa e outras operações de matrizes nos módulos numpy e/ou sympy.

Answer (score 4):

Matriz de origem

```
M =[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
```

Imprimindo

```
for j in M:
    print(j)
```

Saída

```
[1, 2]
[3, 4]
[5, 6]
```

---

Transposta

Criando a matriz

```
M_t = list(map(list, zip(*M)))
```

Imprimindo

```
for j in M_t:
    print(j)
```

Saída

```
[1, 3, 5]
[2, 4, 6]
```

---

Utilizando numpy

```
import numpy as np

M =[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
M_t = np.array(M).T
```

Comment: Solução linda de se ver! Que código limpo!

Comment: Obrigado @Mateus, grande abraço!

Answer (score 4):

Em primeiro lugar, para você calcular a **[transposta](https://www.todamateria.com.br/matriz-transposta/#:%7E:text=A%20transposta%20de%20uma%20matriz,(a%27ji)%20n%20x%20m.)** de uma matriz "A", você precisa da matriz "A". Outra coisa, para você calcular a transposta de uma matriz com ajuda da função **[map()](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/library/functions.html#map)**, você terá de implementar uma função anônima ([lambda](https://wiki.python.org.br/PythonFuncional)). Neste caso, o código pode ser implementado da seguinte forma:

```
a = [[1, 2], [4, 6]]
transposta = list(map(lambda *i: [j for j in i], *a))

print(transposta)
```

Observe que para este código utilizei a matriz:

```
a = [[1, 2], [4, 6]]
```

Ao executar este código, recebemos como resultado:

```
[[1, 4], [2, 6]]
```

Só para reforçar o que já foi dito na outra resposta, matrizes é um assunto bem extenso e que podemos ter melhores resultados se estudarmos melhor as bibliotecas **[numpy](https://numpy.org/)** e **[scipy](https://www.scipy.org/)**.

---

Se você quiser implementar uma função def para calcular a transposta da matriz você pode implementar o seguinte código:

```
def transposta(m):
    return list(map(lambda *i: [j for j in i], *m))


matriz = [[1, 2], [4, 6]]

print(transposta(matriz))
```

Comment: A matriz estava no codigo, só não coloquei esse trecho aqui, com relação a função lambda, eu só consigo resolver esse problema com ela? Não tem como usando def?

Comment: @Wesley Barros, à nível de código Python, existe diversas formas de se calcular a Transposta de uma matriz. Pode sim implementar uma função `def` para calcular a transposta de uma matriz.

Answer (score 4):

Uma solução

```py
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 6, 7, 9], [4, 3, 2, 1]]
*b, = zip(*a)
print(b)
```

Saída

```
[(1, 4, 4), (2, 6, 3), (3, 7, 2), (4, 9, 1)]
```

Answer (score -4):

```
# Experimente esse código (método raiz)
M =[[2, 5], [8, 9], [10, 1]]
m_transposta =[[],[]]
i = 0

for j in M:
  m_transposta[i].append(j[0])
  m_transposta[i+1].append(j[1])

print(m_transposta)

# ou
for j in m_transposta:
  print(j)
```